# Unity2D: UnassignedReferenceException: Variable has not been assigned instantiate

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, instantiation

For some reason I get an error which looks like this:

```
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable LevelComplete of NPad1 has not been assigned.
```

and this is my code:

```
public class NPad1 : MonoBehaviour {
public Sprite img1 , img2;
public Rigidbody2D LevelComplete;

void Start () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img2;
    Instantiate (LevelComplete);
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html);

> Clones the object original and returns the clone.

Which means you will have to instantiate `LevelComplete` before calling `Instantiate()`, which returns a clone of the *existing* object. You probably haven't set the instance in the Unity inspector. For more info, visit [this guide](http://noobtuts.com/unity/show-variables-and-classes-in-inspector) on setting public variables.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I put this code on my Object instead of my Prefab, thank you very much!